# Mark values as being entered by user or calculated by application

Tags: c#, input, state

I'm currently planning a new application. The values used in this application can either be entered by the user or calculated by the application itself.

What I need to do is to mark the values in a way that I can clearly identify the source (user or app).

EDIT (additional information): The idea is not to identify that a user can input a value or not. The idea is to clearly have the possibility to flag values as being calculated or entered by the users. The value will not only be used in the view but also in calculations.

A class A would have a double v. This double can either be calculated or have been entered by a user.

```
class A
{
    public double v;  // <-- this would be the value I'd like to mark as program-defined or user defined
}
```

So, when I do this:

```
v = 1.0;
```

it would be marked as program-defined.

Has anyone a hint on how to achieve this in C#?

In C++ I would create a base class and derive from it. But in C# I would like to take a more general approach which doesn't force me to create a class per input type.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is too broad.  When would you be marking the values?  In an event handler, say the "validated" event of a text field (i.e. typically when the field loses focus)?  In that case, why not just have a boolean that you set in that event to indicate it was entered by the user?

Comment: I'll enhance the question... the idea of a value being entered by a user or calculated by the application has to be transported across the application and not only within a view...

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for way to mark some properties or classes that they are used for user input or internally you can use attributes for this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes

Answer (score 1):

Have a **general class** that **implements a variable** which identifies whether or not it is a value entered by the app or the user.

Possible variable types:

- a **string** ('user', 'app' ...)
- an **enum**, so if the enum is called Source it will be Source.User, if app Source.App.
- an **integer** (as ID)

If you have a limited amount of types I'd personally go with an enum as it allows you to have suggested options. If you have many types I'd go with a string or an integer.

Comment: Wrapping the raw values in a type that identifies where they come from sounds like the right idea. Using an enum for the tags is probably the most straightforward way to do this, but you may also want to explore a generic wrapper type with subclasses to identify the source (more type-safe than enum). In F# I'd use discriminated unions (which under the hood are implemented as a type hierarchy).